# How do I troubleshoot this Excel 2010 crash?

Tags: excel, crash

I am trying to resolve a crash in Excel 2010. It only happens on some machines. These are some of the things I've tried:

- Disabling COM Add-ins
- Changing printer drivers

Any ideas for next steps? See the crash report below.

```
Faulting application name: EXCEL.EXE, version: 14.0.4756.1000, time stamp: 0x4b9c08e8
Faulting module name: unknown, version: 0.0.0.0, time stamp: 0x00000000
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0x00000002
Faulting process id: 0x17b0
Faulting application start time: 0x01ce58a1afa9177d
Faulting application path: C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office14\EXCEL.EXE
Faulting module path: unknown
Report Id: f00ad1ab-c494-11e2-83ea-5c260a8672c5

- <Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
- <System>
  <Provider Name="Application Error" /> 
  <EventID Qualifiers="0">1000</EventID> 
  <Level>2</Level> 
  <Task>100</Task> 
  <Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords> 
  <TimeCreated SystemTime="2013-05-24T17:11:14.000000000Z" /> 
  <EventRecordID>100013</EventRecordID> 
  <Channel>Application</Channel> 
  <Computer>LUSRC0015942.ACME.com</Computer> 
  <Security /> 
  </System>
- <EventData>
  <Data>EXCEL.EXE</Data> 
  <Data>14.0.4756.1000</Data> 
  <Data>4b9c08e8</Data> 
  <Data>unknown</Data> 
  <Data>0.0.0.0</Data> 
  <Data>00000000</Data> 
  <Data>c0000005</Data> 
  <Data>00000002</Data> 
  <Data>17b0</Data> 
  <Data>01ce58a1afa9177d</Data> 
  <Data>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office14\EXCEL.EXE</Data> 
  <Data>unknown</Data> 
  <Data>f00ad1ab-c494-11e2-83ea-5c260a8672c5</Data> 
  </EventData>
  </Event>
```

Answer (score 0):

The exception code: 0xc0000005 seems to indicate an Access Violation error which could be memory, RAM or even a virus.  The following document gives further information

http://compfreakstars.blogspot.co.uk/2011/11/0xc0000005-error-every-day-many.html

If that doesn't resolve it then I'd try and establish a pattern of causation - i.e. what are the users doing when this error happens, what else do they have running etc.  In my experience 9 times out 10 once you establish a pattern then the issue becomes much easier to resolve.

Comment: Hi Andrew, it happens when users are trying to retrieve data into Excel from SQL Server. It only happens on some machines, but not others.

Comment: And does it happen consistently for these users, or is that sporadic as well?  If it happens consistently then I'd check firstly that the data connection is the same between them and a working machine.  If that doesn't bring anything up then I'd probably get one of the working users to log onto a non working machine to try and determine whether it is a machine or server related problem.

Comment: It happens consistently. There is not a data connection problem.

Comment: I think at that stage I'd probably raise a call with Microsoft then!